# What do these numbers mean in apt-get output?

Tags: command-line, apt

Could someone tell me what these numbers mean in apt-get output? (see last line in the image)

1. Percentage at the left.
2. Percentage inside the brackets (at the right)
3. The time at the right (which seems to toggle regularly)

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The percentage completed for total task
2. The percentage of current file being downloaded
3. Estimated remaining time to complete the whole operation